# Looping through Perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I am having problems looping through a Perl array using `foreach`. For some reason, Perl only loops through the first value and then stops.

I am not creating the array manually, it is coming from [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath).

```
print Dumper (@states);

$VAR1 = 'Montana';
$VAR2 = 'Nebraska';
$VAR3 = 'Nevada';
$VAR4 = 'New Hampshire';
$VAR5 = 'New Jersey';
$VAR6 = 'New Mexico';
```

If I dump it out as `\@states`, I get this:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'Montana',
      'Nebraska',
      'Nevada',
      'New Hampshire',
      'New Jersey',
      'New Mexico'
    ];
```

I need to run additional processing on each value, so I am looping through it with a `foreach` loop.

If I run

```
foreach my $state (@states) {
  print $state;
}
```

it only prints `Montana`.

EDIT:

The problem was that I was iterating over the array reference incorrectly. In perl 5.8.8 I had to run it through like:

```
foreach my $state (${@states}) {
    print $state;
}
```

Thanks, sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: It's hard to guess what the problem with your loop if we don't see your loop.

Comment: Note that passing references to arrays and hashes to `Dumper` will provide more clearer results. (e.g. `print Dumper (\@states);`)

Comment: Thanks, sorry, the loop is   foreach my $state (@states) {print $state;} I also tried with \@states and still get a single value, but reference this time.

Comment: I think you need to show your entire program. The code and data you show won't produce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: The correct answer is 

    foreach my $state (\@states) {
   foreach my $s (@$state) {
    print "$s\n";
            }
    }

Comment: That is most definitely *not* the correct answer to the question as you asked it. All that does is dereference a reference to `@states` and loop through the results, which produces the exact same result as simply looping through `@states`. That method is also difficult to read and less efficient than the alternative. As @Borodin said, the code you've shown doesn't produce the behavior you describe, so this question will be useless to any future visitors. Post the code you use to generate `@states` if you want a real answer.

Comment: @user2630270: As *ThisSuitIsBlackNot* says, what you have written is just an extremely confused way of writing the loop you had originally, with the exception that you print a newline after each element of `@states`. Please don't use that *"solution"* in your code. If only you would show your complete program then we would be able to help you get it right.

Answer (score 3):

You should read [the manual here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops)

And here's a sample:

```
my @states = (
   'Montana',       'Nebraska',   'Nevada',
   'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico');

foreach my $state (@states) {
  print "state is $state\n";
}
```

Comment: I am not populating the array manually, it is coming from somewhere HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Comment: @user2630270, It doesn't matter how you populate it. As you see using Data::Dumper, the arrays are the same. And as you can see, the code you said doesn't work does work. You have yet to provide a demonstration of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my @states = ('Montana',      'Nebraska',   'Nevada',
            'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico');

say "Dumping \@states\n" . Dumper @states;

say "\nDumping \\\@states\n" . Dumper \@states;

foreach my $state (@states) {
        print $state;}
```

Here's my results:

```
$ test.pl
MontanaNebraskaNevadaNew HampshireNew JerseyNew Mexico$
```

Prints all the states. However, you're missing the `\n` on the end of your `print`. I would use `say` instead of `print` because `say` automatically adds in the `\n` for you. Less error prone.

I would write the loop this way:

```
for my $state ( @states ) {
    say $state;
}
```

However, as you can see, my Dumper output for `@states` is the same as yours. This means my `@states` is the same as yours, and I print out all of the states (although not on separate lines).

I thought maybe that you somehow have a CR on the end of each of your state names and that was causing problems:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my @states = ("Montana\r",      "Nebraska\r",   "Nevada\r",
            "New Hampshire\r", "New Jersey\r", "New Mexico\r");

say "Dumping \@states\n" . Dumper @states;

say "\nDumping \\\@states\n" . Dumper \@states;

foreach my $state (@states) {
        print $state;}
```

But the output doesn't match your output:

```
$ ./test.pl
Dumping @states
';AR1 = 'Montana
';AR2 = 'Nebraska
';AR3 = 'Nevada
';AR4 = 'New Hampshire
';AR5 = 'New Jersey
';AR6 = 'New Mexico


Dumping \@states
$VAR1 = [
',        'Montana
',        'Nebraska
',        'Nevada
',        'New Hampshire
',        'New Jersey
'         'New Mexico
        ];

$ w Mexicoire
```

Not only is the Dumper different than what you had, but, I'm not printing out `Montana` because I'm overwriting the states each time I print them out.

Something else is going on, and you'll have to give us more information what is going on. As the old programmer dictum states: *It works on **my** machine*.